# Is it possible to Give to Moq (or any other mocking api) a default implementation?

Tags: .net, moq

This is the scenario:

```
interface IFather
{
    void A();
}

interface ISonA : IFather
{
    void B();
}
```

and I have a default implementation for IFather

```
private class Father : IFather
{
    public void A()
    {
        //default behaviour
    }
}
```

Is it possible to mock ISonA (or any other ISon that implements IFather) with default behaviour provided by Father? I would like to do something like this:

```
    var mock = new Mock<ISonA>(typeof(Father));
    //with A nothing, use default behaviour
    //mock.Setup(x => x.A()).Callback(() =>  /*something*/);
    mock.Setup(x => x.B()).Callback(() =>  /*something*/);
```

Where typeof(Father) is the way to tell Mock to internally implement ISonA extending Father. Currently the only way to achieve this is by using my own SonA class instead of mocking it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution. Some fixes were required to the previous example. At the end the complete code is shown. 
1º method A() has to be marked as virtual en the class Father.
2º mock has to be configured with the property CallBase = true

```
public interface IFather
{
    int A();
}

public interface ISon : IFather
{
    int B();
}

public class Father : IFather
{
    public virtual int A()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Test Code

```
var mock = new Mock<Father>().As<ISon>();
mock.CallBase = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution! The mock should be created like this:

```
var mock = new Mock<Father>().As<ISonA>();
```

In this way I inherit Father's implementation and get a ISonA mock at the same time

Comment: Unfortunatly the previous example compiles but it doesn't work. Mock doesn't use Father.A()